# Laravel: How should I update this relationship?

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

Suppose I have the following tables:

```
User:
-userID
-userName
...

Exercises:
-exerciseID
...
```

`User` model:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'userID';

...

    public function hasPassedExercises() {
        return $this->hasMany('Exercise', 'exerciseID');
    }

}
```

I want to say that a `User` has many `completedExercises`, so when the user completes an exercise, I update the model like so:

```
    Route::post('dbm/userPassedExercise', function () {
        $user = User::with('hasPassedExercises')->find($_POST['userID']);

        $exercise = Exercise::find($_POST['exerciseID']);
        $user->hasPassedExercises->save($exercise);
    });
```

However, this has no effect on any underlying table, as far as I have understood. I'm trying to make sense of the documentation and see how it applies to my problem. So my question is what is the right course of action to do here.

Should I create a table `users_completed_exercises` that has `userID` and `exerciseID` as foreign keys, and if so, how do I link them to my user when I do the update? Or is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you have to use a relationship table (called pivot table).

In the laravel documentation, you have to name your pivot table with your tables name ordered by their name (you have not to, but it's prefered).
We'll take your naming convention so : users_completed_exercises

So here we shoud have this  :

```
users:
   - userId // Unsigned Int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT

Exercises:
   - exerciseId // Unsigned Int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT

users_completed_exercises:
   - id // Unsigned Int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
   - exerciseId // Unsigned Int FOREIGN KEY REFERECES EXERCICES ON ID
   - userId // Unsigned Int FOREIGN KEY REFERECES USERS ON ID
```

On the user model, you should have :

```
public function passedExercises()
{
   // Alphabetical order of your id's are here, very important because laravel
   // retreives the good ID with your table name.
   return $this->belongsToMany('Exercise', 'users_completed_exercises', 'exerciseId', 'userId');
}
```

And the inverse on Excercise Model

```
public function usersWhoPassed()
{
   // Alphabetical order of your id's are here, very important because laravel
   // retreives the good ID with your table name.
   return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'users_completed_exercises', 'exerciseId', 'userId');
}
```

Retreiving infos are now, so easy.

```
Route::post('dbm/userPassedExercise', function () {
    // Don't use $_POST with laravel, they are exceptions indeed, but avoid as much as
    // possible.
    $user = User::find(Input::get('userId'));

    $exercise = Exercise::find(Input::get('exerciseId'));
    // Very important, use () on relationships only if you want to continue the query
    // Without () you will get an Exercises Collection. Use ->get() or ->first() to end
    // the query and get the result(s)
    $exercise->usersWhoPassed()->save($user);
});
```

You can easly check if user has passed an exercise too

```
Route::get('/exercises/{id}/passed_users', function($id)
{
    $exercise = Exercise::find($id);

    if ($exercise->usersWhoPassed()
        ->where('userId', '=', Input::get('userId'))->count()) {
       return 'User has passed';
    }
    return 'User has failed';
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. However, I get the error `Class 'users_completed_exercises' not found`on the save line. Do I need to make a model for the pivot table?

Comment: You do not have to make a model for the pivot table. Laravel does it for you.

I did not do the usual checks on entity.
Did you check if $exercise realy exists after your Exercise::find() ?

-Forgive my english, not my native language-

Comment: It does, I checked with a `var_dump`.

Comment: Can you past the result of var_dump ?
(little trick, use dd (framework method) instead of var_dump)

Comment: OK, I am sorry, was my mistake in the hurry to go to lunch.
Add the inverse Model name at the first arguments of belongsTo.
I updated my answer, check it.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you once again.

Comment: I had to change the last line in the `post` to
    ```$exercise->usersWhoPassed()->save($user);```
otherwise, I get an error that the foreign key constraint fails because of duplicate entries.

Comment: Oh, ok. Strange because it has to work in both way.
But i have updated my answer.
Thank you for your feedback

Comment: Use attach() instead of save() will work in both way.
Tested on my dev environment.
Attach will not try to save the entity whereas save will.